# How to match multiple specific scala versions in source directory in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

The sbt documentation tells me I can suffix the scala version in order to get sbt to pick up the sources when building with that version.

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html#Scala-version+specific+source+directory

It doesn't say how I can specify the suffix so that I can match multiple scala versions in one directory. I need one to match both `2.12` and `2.13`, and one to match `2.11`.

I found a few example of that in a few libraries like `zio` or `cats`. The suffixes looked like `-2.12+` or `-2.12-2.13`. When applied to my build though, sbt doesn't seem to find these paths, and compilation fails because some classes are not found. If I separate them with `-2.12` and `-2.13` it works, but I'd have to duplicate code.

You can try `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8` and rename `src/main/scala` to `src/main/scala-2.12+` and see that it doesn't work, while it works when renamed to `src/main/scala-2.13`.

Can someone point me to what I'm missing?
I've tried sbt versions `1.3.10` and `1.2.8`.

Comment: Those libraries do a custom configuration to allow that, you may check their code and replicate it.

Comment: Ah thanks. I thought I was missing an option or something.